# Htaccess - remove .php extension and keep query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've tried to remove the `.php` extension and keep the `id` query parameter, but I get a 404 error.

This is the URL:

```
example.com/folder/file.php?q=123
```

And I want it to be:

```
example.com/folder/file/123
```

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$1/(.*)$ /$1.php?q=$2
```

Comment: To clarify, you are actually making requests to URLs of the form `/folder/file/123` (since `.htaccess` itself doesn't actually "change" the URL). The `.htaccess` file is presumably in the document root directory?

Comment: Do you need to also handle extensionless URLs _without_ additional parameters? eg. `/folder/file`?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

This would internally rewrite the URL from `/folder/file/123` to `/folder/file/123.php`, which is obviously going to result in a 404. It would be preferable to test that the corresponding `.php` file exists, rather than testing that the request does not already map to a file.

I'm assuming the `q` URL parameter always takes a numeric value.

Try the following instead:

```
# Rewrite "/folder/<file>/<123>" to "/folder/<file>.php?q=<123>"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?q=$2 [L]
```

The `NC` flag is not required.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$1/(.*)$ /$1.php?q=$2
> ```

This rule doesn't make sense and is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming last path component makes query parameter `q`, you can use this rule:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# ignore all files and directories from rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Add .php extension and use last component as parameter q
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?q=$2 [L,QSA]

# Add .php extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```